# 7z batch file create individual( 7z or zip) with a master PW

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, zip, 7-zip

I use this command with notepad. Save it as 7z.bat in a folder you want to individually .7z or .zip the files. With -p{pasword} -mhe *.txt

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO (
  ECHO "%%i" | FIND /I "7z.bat" 1>NUL) || (
    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%%~ni.7z" "%%i" -psuperuser -mhe *.txt
    if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 del "%%i"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I add password to each file?

Use the `-p` command switch.

Example:

```
7z a archive.7z -psecret -mhe *.txt
```

Source: [-p (set Password) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/password.htm)